# PHP turn off all errors but save errors to error_log

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm on a shared hosting and want to hide all errors from the visitors so I use error_reporting(0) but this will lead to erros not saving in the error_log file that's created in the directory where the file is located. How to turn off erros but add them to the error_log?

Tried display_errors,0 but it seems my shared host is not allowing the edit of ini

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ini_set("display_errors", 0);
ini_set("log_errors", 1);

//Define where do you want the log to go, syslog or a file of your liking with
ini_set("error_log", "syslog");
```